# Multivariate Calculus, Aggregrate from density

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $x$ be the logarithm of the amount of rainfall on a given day, and
let $y$ be the logarithm of the average temperature of that day.

The probability density of $(x, y)$ occurring is $$p(x, y) = 1/(2π) e^{-(x^2 + y^2)/2}.$$

The weather station decides that if $(x,y)$ lies in the unit disk centered at the origin, then they will display the cloudy symbol on their website as the forecast for the day. What is the probability that the cloudy symbol will be displayed on a given day?

My attempt to this question is firstly, to find the boundaries for integration, for which I changed the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates $(r, θ).$

Then the integral I have is
$$∬1/(2π)  e^{-(r^2)/2} dθdr,$$ with boundaries $$B={(r\cosθ, r\sinθ): 0≤θ≤2π,\, 0≤r≤1}.$$

Is my approach correct? I got stuck while integrating $e^{-(r^2)/2}$.

Anyone please help solving this question!

Comment: Welcome to MathExchange. Use proper MathJax please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your integration is wrong. $dxdy=rdrd\theta$.

Then... I let the legion as $D={(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\mid 0\le\theta<2\pi,\, 0\le r\le1}.$

Then your integral is
$$\iint_D\frac1{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2}dxdy=\iint_D\frac1{2\pi}e^{-\frac{r^2}2}rdrd\theta=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1re^{-\frac{r^2}2}drd\theta$$
$$
=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1re^{-\frac{r^2}2}dr=\int_0^1re^{-\frac{r^2}2}dr=\left[-e^{\frac{r^2}2}\right]_0^1=1-\frac1{\sqrt e}
$$

Comment: Oh my, realised I missed out adding the r when converting to polar coordinates. Thanks so much for the help!